# Tool to remove upgrade to Windows 10 prompt

Tags: windows

Something exceedingly simple for someone exceedingly computer illiterate, please.

Just to remove that nagging prompt to upgrade from Windows 7 to 10.

Comment: Are you referring to the Upgrade to Windows 10 (if you're on Windows 7 or 8) or the updates for Windows 10 (stop receiving all windows 10 updates)?

Comment: Sorry, I was typing on a small phone, whch I hate doing & didn't explain well enough. Question is updated now. Thanks for prompting me

Comment: Lolx 2 upvotes and 3 close votes. I really didn't explain well  :-)

Comment: My apologies, didn't see your comment and edit until now, I've removed my close vote and upvoted your question.

Comment: Thanks (+1). I did deserve it in the original version, though.

Answer (score 9):

Two programs:

[GWX Control Panel](http://ultimateoutsider.com/downloads/)

> This is a free tool that can remove and disable the 'Get Windows 10' notification area icon on Windows 7 and Windows 8. Recent versions can also disable 'Upgrade to Windows 10' behavior in the Windows Update control panel and do much more.

[Never10](https://www.grc.com/never10.htm)

This simply toggles the 'allow the 10 update' using a MS recommended way (registry settings). This recommended method also removes any downloads already in progress.
It does not install anything, and also handles that you may need to update Windows Update first.

**I recommend Never10** for its simplicity. It is written by Steve Gibson who initially was a big fan of GWX Control Panel, but found it to become 'too complex', after playing cat-and-mouse with Microsoft for several generations.

[*Update 22-4-2016*]
A new update Version 1.3 of Never10 was announced earlier this month. It turns out that previous versions did *not* properly clean up the partial Windows downloads. If you re-run version 1.3 or later this will fix that. On one Win8 test system these temp downloads took up a whopping 6.5 GB, so it's well worth cleaning up.
Version 1.3 also introduces command-line support.

Comment: Wow, Never10 is a utility made by Steve Gibson, who I think still loves programming everything in assembler, and came up with so many detail-loving, compact solutions in the last years -- even Never10 inherits the clear, simple user interface design that clearly carries his very personal signature.

Answer (score 6):

You can take a look at what [HowToGeek](http://www.howtogeek.com/218856/how-do-you-disable-the-get-windows-10-icon-shown-in-the-notification-tray/) has to say about this.

I created a little file that will modify the registry so it completely disables the icon and the prompt.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Gwx]

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Gwx]
"DisableGwx"=dword:00000001
```

Just save the source code to `YourFileName.reg` and click to run it.

Comment: Thanks. I will let you when it works (whcih I am sure that it will)

Comment: Almost certainly need to right click and "Run as Admin"